# Error in Disquisitiones Arithmeticae: Error by publisher?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Article 30 of Gauss's *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*:

> "If this is again solved relative to the modulus $2$, it becomes $x' \equiv 1 \pmod 2$, and letting $x' \equiv 1 + 2x''$, this becomes $38x'' \equiv -28 \pmod{70}$ or $19x'' \equiv -4 \pmod{35}$."

We should have the congruence $19x'' \equiv -14 \pmod{35}$. I hope that this is a simple error in my copy of the book and I want to make sure that it isn't widespread. Can you please check your copy and let me know?

Comment: I've no copy of that book but when a mistake is so obvious and simple who cares? Well, perhaps as a historic curiosity, but for that...

Comment: I have a copy, and the error is as you stated. Maybe this is indeed an error of the publisher...

Comment: [Gauss](http://www.gaussfacts.com/) is the author, therefore the error was made by the publisher.

Comment: I noticed the same mistake in my English translation copy (Clarke, Yale U. Press, 1968), but not in my German translation copy (1981 reprint of 1889 publication). Given the nature of your question, it might not hurt to provide at least a little information on which copy you are using!

Answer (score 5):

It is $-14 \pmod{35}$ [in the original Latin text](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/content/PPN235993352/800/0/00000027.jpg), so I'm sure it's the publisher's mistake.